# Convert a column in pandas of HH:MM to minutes

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, timedelta

I want to convert a column in dataset of hh:mm format to minutes. I tried the following code but it says " AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split' ". The data is in following format. I also have nan values in the dataset and the plan is to compute the median of values and then fill the rows which has nan with the median

```
02:32
02:14
02:31
02:15
02:28
02:15
02:22
02:16
02:22
02:14
```

I have tried this so far

```
 s = dataset['Enroute_time_(hh mm)']

   hours, minutes = s.split(':')
   int(hours) * 60 + int(minutes)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `split` you will need to use the `str` accessor, ie `s.str.split(':')`.

However I think that in this case it makes more sense to use `apply`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Enroute_time_(hh mm)': ['02:32', '02:14', '02:31', 
                                            '02:15', '02:28', '02:15', 
                                            '02:22', '02:16', '02:22', '02:14']})

def convert_to_minutes(value):
    hours, minutes = value.split(':')
    return int(hours) * 60 + int(minutes)

df['Enroute_time_(hh mm)'] = df['Enroute_time_(hh mm)'].apply(convert_to_minutes)
print(df)

#       Enroute_time_(hh mm)
#    0                   152
#    1                   134
#    2                   151
#    3                   135
#    4                   148
#    5                   135
#    6                   142
#    7                   136
#    8                   142
#    9                   134
```

Comment: I tried your answer, it says "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'"

Comment: @prateeksingh it means that you have some float values somewhere in your column, probably `NaN`?

Comment: all the values are of same format. But it does have some nan values. My plan is to convert it into minutes and then fill the nan values with the median of the  rest of the values.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you avoid row-wise calculations. You can use a vectorised approach with Pandas / NumPy:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': ['02:32', '02:14', '02:31', '02:15', '02:28', '02:15', 
                            '02:22', '02:16', '02:22', '02:14', np.nan]})

values = df['time'].fillna('00:00').str.split(':', expand=True).astype(int)
factors = np.array([60, 1])

df['mins'] = (values * factors).sum(1)

print(df)

     time  mins
0   02:32   152
1   02:14   134
2   02:31   151
3   02:15   135
4   02:28   148
5   02:15   135
6   02:22   142
7   02:16   136
8   02:22   142
9   02:14   134
10    NaN     0
```

Comment: I also have nan values in the dataset. My plan is to use median of the current values and then fill those nan rows with the Median. Your method is right but is not able to deal with nan values. What should I do about it ?

Answer (score 1):

I understood that you have a column in a DataFrame with multiple Timedeltas as Strings. Then you want to extract the total minutes of the Deltas. After that you want to fill the NaN values with the median of the total minutes.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
     {'hhmm' : ['02:32',
                '02:14',
                '02:31',
                '02:15',
                '02:28',
                '02:15',
                '02:22',
                '02:16',
                '02:22',
                '02:14']})
```

1. Your Timedeltas are not Timedeltas. They are strings. So you need to convert them first.

   ```
   df.hhmm = pd.to_datetime(df.hhmm, format='%H:%M')
   df.hhmm = pd.to_timedelta(df.hhmm - pd.datetime(1900, 1, 1))
   ```

   This gives you the following values (*Note the dtype: timedelta64[ns] here*)

   ```
   0   02:32:00
   1   02:14:00
   2   02:31:00
   3   02:15:00
   4   02:28:00
   5   02:15:00
   6   02:22:00
   7   02:16:00
   8   02:22:00
   9   02:14:00
   Name: hhmm, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
   ```
2. Now that you have true timedeltas, you can use some cool functions like `total_seconds()` and then calculate the minutes.

   ```
   df.hhmm.dt.total_seconds() / 60
   ```
3. If that is not what you wanted, you can also use the following.

   ```
   df.hhmm.dt.components.minutes
   ```

   This gives you the minutes from the HH:MM string as if you would have split it.
4. Fill the na-values.

   ```
    df.hhmm.fillna((df.hhmm.dt.total_seconds() / 60).mean())
   ```

   or

   ```
   df.hhmm.fillna(df.hhmm.dt.components.minutes.mean())
   ```