# Using lambda or apply on multiple columns of a dataframe with lists contents

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

This may be a trivial question. I have the following dataframe that the columns contain lists.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'time1': [['2000', '2300'], ['1000', '1100']], 'time2': [['2200', '2400'], ['800', '900']]})
print(df)

  time1         time2
0  [2000, 2300]  [2200, 2400]
1  [1000, 1100]    [800, 900]
```

The values in of the list represent time intervals. I am trying to convert all these elements into a time format.

I am trying to get something like this:

```
time1         time2
20:00-23:00  22:00-24:00
10:00-11:00  8:00-9:00
```

Comment: You want the output in string type? Or pandas timedelta?

Comment: Doesnt matter. String is fine.

Comment: I would use applymap to apply a function to each individual value (in this case a list) stored in your dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can define our function here to unnest your list and seperate the strings with a `:` delimiter, then apply it to each column:

```
functime = lambda x: '-'.join([t[:-2] + ':' + t[-2:] for t in x])

for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(functime)
```

---

```
print(df)
         time1        time2
0  20:00-23:00  22:00-24:00
1  10:00-11:00    8:00-9:00
```

**Or**

Define a regular function:

```
def functime2(x):
    val = '-'.join([t[:-2] + ':' + t[-2:] for t in x])

    return val

for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(functime2)
```

---

```
         time1        time2
0  20:00-23:00  22:00-24:00
1  10:00-11:00    8:00-9:00
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one indirect way to do it based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53098753/4932316) unaccepted answer. The idea is to split the string into hours and minutes and then join them using a dash `-` and `:`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'time1': [['2000', '2300'], ['1000', '1100']], 
                   'time2': [['2200', '2400'], ['800', '900']]})


def convert_to_minutes(value):
    tim = []
    for val in value:
        hours, minutes = val[0:-2], val[-2:]
        tim.append(hours + ':' + minutes)

    return '-'.join(tim)

df['time1'] = df['time1'].apply(convert_to_minutes)
df['time2'] = df['time2'].apply(convert_to_minutes)
```

**Output**

```
print (df)

         time1        time2
 0  20:00-23:00  22:00-24:00
 1  10:00-11:00    8:00-9:00
```